# Xcode iOS blinking button stuck

Tags: objective-c

Hey I implemented a function in my iOS app that makes a button blink, and stop that if a certain parameter is set. I lost all the app data and recoded everything but I am struggling to figure out an issue I have in here now.

My method looks like this:

```
- (void)toggleButtonImage:(NSTimer*)timer
{    
    toggle = !toggle; // is a bool
    for(int x=0;x<9;x++){
        for (int y=0;y<9;y++){
            if(toggle==true){ 
                if (blinks[x][y]==1){ 
                    [buttons[x][y] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }

            else if (toggle==false) {
                    [buttons[x][y] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newmask"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All the buttons are in a kind of table and the method goes through all of them, checks if the `blinks` array for a button is set to 1 and if it is, it sets a dark image as background. On every second run, it sets the picture of the button to "newmask", no matter what `blinks` says.

So if `blinks` is on 1, the button always switches between "newmask" and "loading".

However, about 50% of the buttons are stuck on the `loading` picture and don't even get refreshed later on, as if they were ignored. I am sure I am just missing out some simple logic here, but what could it be? Setting `blinks` to 1 again gives another 50% chance of eventually having the button on "newmask", but, as always, it is just a 50% chance of having the button on "newmask" after having `blinks` set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I THINK it had something to do with the main queue being overwritten. However, I now have written this method:

```
- (void)toggleButtonImage:(NSTimer*)timer
{    
    if(go) fl=fl-1;
    else fl++;

    if(fl>4) go=true;
    if(fl<2) go=false;

for(int x=0;x<kButtonColumns;x++){
    for (int y=0;y<kButtonRows;y++){
        if(blinks[x][y]==1)  //  if(toggle)
           {
             [buttons[x][y]  setAlpha:0.2*fl];
        }
        else {
             [buttons[x][y]  setAlpha:1.0];
        }
    }
  }
   toggle = !toggle;
}
```

I have a refresh rate of 0.08s, resulting in a frame rate of 12.5fps which is a solid compromise between performance and looks. Additionally, I set the direction (bool go) and the starting value for the int fl on 6 every time I someone hits the button, so the user gets the feeling of actually controlling the animation.

```
- (void) sete{
    fl=6;
    go=true;
}

- (IBAction)actionPick:(id)sender
{
    [self sete]; 
...
```